# How to get max value with 3 inner joins?

Tags: mysql, database

Need help with getting the max value for Grade with inner joins.

---

Code:

```
SELECT StudFirstName, StudLastName, sc.ClassID, sub.SubjectID, sub.CategoryID, Grade
FROM SS_Students as st INNER JOIN SS_Student_Schedules as ss
ON st.StudentID = ss.StudentID
INNER JOIN SS_Classes as sc
ON ss.ClassID = sc.ClassID
INNER JOIN SS_Subjects as sub
ON sc.SubjectID = sub.SubjectID;
```

Just need to get the max value for Grade so the output will shorten down to 1 row.

Comment: You can use `SELECT MAX(Grade) FROM ...`

Comment: @Nish Patel you want only max value or you want complete detail that which student get max Grade with subject detail??

Comment: ORDER BY grade DESC LIMIT 1; Otherwise, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Ashutosh SIngh i want the complete detail that which student got the max grade with subject detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use group by and max like:

```
SELECT StudFirstName, StudLastName, sc.ClassID, sub.SubjectID, sub.CategoryID, MAX(Grade)
FROM SS_Students as st INNER JOIN SS_Student_Schedules as ss
    ON st.StudentID = ss.StudentID
INNER JOIN SS_Classes as sc
    ON ss.ClassID = sc.ClassID
INNER JOIN SS_Subjects as sub
    ON sc.SubjectID = sub.SubjectID
GROUP BY StudFirstName, StudLastName, sc.ClassID, sub.SubjectID, sub.CategoryID
```

This will give you the student list and max grade for each student.